# How to add package to dotnet for WPF app?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, testing, code-coverage

I am trying to add a package to dotnet using a command:

```
dotnet add package JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools --version 2018.2.0-eap07
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
The project does not support adding package references through the add package command.
```

How can I do it? I cannot install the package through NuGet as my dotnet command line will not detect dotcover. I saw some example adding package through .csproj for dotnet.core apps:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools" Version="2018.2.0-eap03" />
```

And then running the dotnet restore. But I don't know how to do it for WPF apps. My end goal is to use the following command for the WPF app to produce test coverage:

```
dotnet dotcover test
```

Comment: Does dotnet already support WPF?

Comment: For just basic commands like "dotnet test" , "dotnet build" etc. it works fine

Comment: sometimes this error `The project does not support adding package` happened because you are in the solution level and dotnet can't find the correct project file. or sometimes you may use `docker-compose.dcproj` that confused the dotnet command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dotnet` is a .NET **Core** command-line interface and WPF doesn't yet support .NET core. So you can't currently reference a .NET Core library from a WPF application.

You can add a reference to a .NET standard library from both a WPF application and a .NET Core application, but you can't reference a .NET Core library from a .NET Framework application and vice versa.

WPF will eventually be able to run on .NET Core 3: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/